# dplyr mutate across to create a new column and modify all columns in the data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have some data which looks like:

```
   column1    column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8  column9 column10
   <chr>      <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   <lgl>   
 1 company42  NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA      NA      
 2 company105 NA      €315k   NA      NA      NA      NA      Mar 2015 NA      NA      
 3 company23  NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA      NA      
 4 company70  NA      €570    NA      NA      NA      NA      Apr 2016 NA      NA
```

I want to do two things to it.

1. Extract all of the EUR signs and put them into a column "currency" - each row contains currency data where the currency is unique across the columns but it can change down the rows.
2. Convert all of the "K" to "000" and all of the "M" to "000000".

Expected output:

```
   column1    column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8  column9 column10  column 11
   <chr>      <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   <lgl>       <chr>
 1 company42  NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA      NA            NA
 2 company105 NA      315000  NA      NA      NA      NA      Mar 2015 NA      NA            €
 3 company23  NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA      NA            NA
 4 company70  NA      570    NA      NA      NA      NA      Apr 2016 NA      NA             €
```

Where the new column 11 has been added and the € removed from column 3 and finally the "K" has been converted to "000".

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(column1 = c("company42", "company105", "company23", 
"company70", "company77", "company51", "company20", "company17", 
"company78", "company80", "company39", "company37", "company101", 
"company61", "company104", "company41", "company88", "company131", 
"company102", "company45"), column2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "\20060k", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), column3 = c(NA, "\200315k", NA, "\200570", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "$1.05M", NA, NA, "\200177k", NA, NA, NA, "\20070k", NA, 
NA, "\200223k"), column4 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), column5 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), column6 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "\200653k", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), column7 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), column8 = c(NA, 
"Mar 2015", NA, "Apr 2016", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Sep 2012", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Jul 2014", NA, NA, "May 2016"), column9 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    column10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: While @SteveM's comment is in no way helpful (and should be flagged as unfriendly or unkind), his point is valid. It is generally better to show your work than simply ask "how do I do this", to illustrate that you have given some effort to try and solve your own problem. Maybe you were fairly close already, and users can alter your code slightly to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Your data is also very "obscure" in the sense that it has a large amount of `NA` columns. Is your value always in the 3'rd column,  or are there some condition for which columns contain currencies? It becomes a lot more cumbersome if all you know is "some columns may contain currencies, while others contain only text".

Comment: Yes, the data has many NA values. The value is not always in the 3rd column. For example the following `summarise(across(.cols = everything(), .fns =  ~str_extract(., pattern = "€")))` extracts the EUR sign but I want this collapsed down into a single column. This also seems to solve the issue of point 2 `summarise(across(.cols = everything(), .fns =  ~str_replace(., pattern = "k", replacement = "000")))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach, maybe is not the most optimal but it can address you to a new path when modifying it:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code 1
data2 <- data %>% mutate(across(column2:column7,~ifelse(grepl('k',.),gsub('k','000',.),
                                               ifelse(grepl('M',.),gsub('M','000000',.),.))))
#Code 2
data2$Currency <- apply(data2[,2:7],1,
                        function(x) trimws(gsub('NA','',
                                         paste0(gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", x),
                                                collapse = ',')),whitespace = ','))
data2$Currency <- gsub('\\.','',data2$Currency)
#Code 3
data3 <- data2 %>% mutate(across(column2:column7,~gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", .)))
data3 <- data3 %>% mutate(across(column2:column7,~gsub("€", "", .)))
data3 <- data3 %>% mutate(across(column2:column7,as.numeric))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 11
   column1    column2   column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8  column9 column10 Currency
   <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>   <lgl>    <chr>   
 1 company42       NA        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA       NA      NA       ""      
 2 company105      NA    315000      NA      NA      NA      NA Mar 2015 NA      NA       "€"     
 3 company23       NA        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA       NA      NA       ""      
 4 company70       NA       570      NA      NA      NA      NA Apr 2016 NA      NA       "€"     
 5 company77       NA        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA       NA      NA       ""      
 6 company51       NA        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA       NA      NA       ""      
 7 company20       NA        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA       NA      NA       ""      
 8 company17       NA        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA       NA      NA       ""      
 9 company78       NA        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA       NA      NA       ""      
10 company80       NA 105000000      NA      NA      NA      NA Sep 2012 NA      NA       "$"     
11 company39       NA        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA       NA      NA       ""      
12 company37       NA        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA       NA      NA       ""      
13 company101   60000    177000      NA      NA      NA      NA NA       NA      NA       "€,€"   
14 company61       NA        NA      NA      NA  653000      NA NA       NA      NA       "€"     
15 company104      NA        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA       NA      NA       ""      
16 company41       NA        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA       NA      NA       ""      
17 company88       NA     70000      NA      NA      NA      NA Jul 2014 NA      NA       "€"     
18 company131      NA        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA       NA      NA       ""      
19 company102      NA        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA       NA      NA       ""      
20 company45       NA    223000      NA      NA      NA      NA May 2016 NA      NA       "€"
```

Comment: This solution is more elegant than mine.  Caution using grepl or gsub on large datasets though.  stringr is at least an order of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
> data %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(column11 = case_when(any(grepl('\u20AC', c_across(column2:column10))) ~ '\u20AC',
+                                                    any(grepl('\\$', c_across(column2:column10))) ~ '$', TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
+   mutate(across(2:10, ~ str_remove_all(., '\\$|\u20AC'))) %>% mutate(across(2:10, ~ case_when(grepl('k$',.) ~ parse_number(.)*1000,
+                                                                                               grepl('M$',.) ~ parse_number(.)*1000000,
+                                                                                               TRUE ~ NA_real_)))
# A tibble: 20 x 11
# Rowwise: 
   column1    column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8 column9 column10 column11
   <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>   
 1 company42       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA NA      
 2 company105      NA  315000      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA €       
 3 company23       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA NA      
 4 company70       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA €       
 5 company77       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA NA      
 6 company51       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA NA      
 7 company20       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA NA      
 8 company17       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA NA      
 9 company78       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA NA      
10 company80       NA 1050000      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA $       
11 company39       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA NA      
12 company37       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA NA      
13 company101   60000  177000      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA €       
14 company61       NA      NA      NA      NA  653000      NA      NA      NA       NA €       
15 company104      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA NA      
16 company41       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA NA      
17 company88       NA   70000      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA €       
18 company131      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA NA      
19 company102      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA NA      
20 company45       NA  223000      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA €       
>
```

Comment: Almost. However "company80" should have a dollar sign in the column11

Comment: @user8959427, have made the change, can you please check now.